# D3 and leaflet returning different SVG in Chrome/Safari and Firefox

Tags: svg, d3.js, leaflet

I am follow [this](https://gist.github.com/AbeHandler/9926786) example to make a map with leaflet and d3, using the latest versions of d3 and leaflet. Something in my code is causing d3 to return different values for the SVG elements in Chrome and FF 28. This is causing the points to be skewed in FF, which has different d values in the PATH elements as well as different transform properties in the SVG elements.

Here is the SVG for Chrome:

```xml
<svg width="1049711" height="1802" transform="translate(127,1079)" style="margin-left: -127px; margin-top: -1079px;">
<g class="leaflet-zoom-hide" transform="translate(127,1079)">
<path class="nora f" id="1383_ST_BERNARD_AVE" lat="29.970905251" long="90.064206456" d="M287,210m0,2a2,2 0 1,1 0,-4a2,2 0 1,1 0,4z"></path>
<path class="fixed f" id="7400_ADVENTURE_AVE" lat="30.0599104550001" long="89.9260116889999" d="M1092,-389m0,2a2,2 0 1,1 0,-4a2,2 0 1,1 0,4z"></path>
```

Here is the SVG for Firefox

```xml
<svg width="1049711" height="1802" style="margin-left: -97px; margin-top: -1079px;" transform="translate(97,1079)">
<g class="leaflet-zoom-hide" transform="translate(97,1079)">
<path class="nora f" id="1383_ST_BERNARD_AVE" lat="29.970905251" long="90.064206456" d="M317,210m0,2a2,2 0 1,1 0,-4a2,2 0 1,1 0,4z"/>
<path class="fixed f" id="7400_ADVENTURE_AVE" lat="30.0599104550001" long="89.9260116889999" d="M1122,-389m0,2a2,2 0 1,1 0,-4a2,2 0 1,1 0,4z"/><path class="nora f" id="4170_OLD_GENTILLY_RD" lat="30.0024662600001" long="90.0401487569999" d="M457,-3m0,2a2,2 0 1,1 0,-4a2,2 0 1,1 0,4z"/>
```

Here is the code that loads the map and projects the points. At the very end there is a function `project` that returns a different x-value for the point in Chrome and FF 28.  I think that this line is creating the overall problem with the code. The x-value is off by different values at different times, so it is hard to write a correction.

```
    var map = new L.Map("map", {center: [29.95, -90.05], zoom: 13, minZoom:10, maxZoom:18})
        .addLayer(new L.tileLayer('http://{s}.www.toolserver.org/tiles/bw-mapnik/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'));

    var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg"),
       g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide");

    //these brackets are jinja2 template syntax. They eventually return 'static/out.json' 
    d3.json('out.json') }}', function(collection) {
     var bounds = d3.geo.bounds(collection),
      path = d3.geo.path().projection(project).pointRadius(function (d) {return 2});
    console.warn(path)

     var feature = g.selectAll("path")
      .data(collection.features)
    .enter().append("path").attr("class", function(d){
      return d.properties.category + " " + d.properties.investigates;;
    }).attr("id", function(d){
      return d.geometry.address;
    }).attr("lat", function(d){
       return Math.abs(d.geometry.coordinates[1]);
    }).attr("long", function(d){
       return Math.abs(d.geometry.coordinates[0]);
    });
    $(".t").on("click", function(e) {

        var adr = "/" + this.id;
        showDialog(adr);
    });

      map.on("viewreset", reset);
      reset();


      // Reposition the SVG to cover the features.
      function reset() {
        console.warn(bounds)
        var bottomLeft = project(bounds[0]),
            topRight = project(bounds[1]);


    svg .attr("width", topRight[0] - bottomLeft[0])
        .attr("height", bottomLeft[1] - topRight[1])
        .style("margin-left", bottomLeft[0] + "px")
        .style("margin-top", topRight[1] + "px").attr("transform", "translate(" + -bottomLeft[0] + "," + -topRight[1] + ")");

     g .attr("transform", "translate(" + -bottomLeft[0] + "," + -topRight[1] + ")");

    feature.attr("d", path)
  }

      // Use Leaflet to implement a D3 geographic projection.
      function project(x) {
        var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(x[1], x[0]));
        return [point.x, point.y];
      }          
      });
```

I [proposed this as a bug](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2628) to leaflet. If you try the fiddle in FF 28 and Chrome you will see that line 51 returns different x-values for the same lat/long in Chrome (right x value) and firefox (wrong x value)

I have tried this fiddle in FF 27 and FF 28 -- each of these versions of firefox returns a different (and incorrect) x-value for the point on line 51.

Have I hit a bug in leaflet or d3 or is there an issue with my code? Is there a workaround? What's going on here?

Comment: If you remove the little correction you added, does it work?

Comment: @robertc If I remove the correction the translate and margin left properties of the SVG element are still different in chrome and in FF -- and the points still do not project to their correct locations in FF

Comment: The correction you added is most certainly causing the immediate problem. can you remove it and post the resulting SVG elements (as markup, not as images, please!) that are different. It seems unlikely that d3.js is producing different values in FF and webkit.

Comment: @StephenThomas See my edits. The correction is not causing the problem

Comment: The differences that I see are in the left margin and x-axis translation, and both of those are coming from the `project` function, which uses the Leaflet API. None of that has anything to do with d3. Is there something I'm missing that makes you suspect d3?

Comment: @StephenThomas Nope. I am not super familiar with leaflet. I added a leaflet tag too

Comment: Any chance you can find an old version of Firefox to test this out on?  [FF28 has a bug relating to path lengths](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22894881/3128209), it's possible they've got other bugs that are affecting Leaflet's internal calculations.

Comment: @AmeliaBR see my edit. I get different values for the x length in FF 27 and 28 -- each of the values is incorrect.

Comment: Hmm.  Well, it definitely sounds like the problem stems from the way FF is implementing methods used by Leaflet, but if FF27 is still giving incorrect values it can't *just* be that one bug.  I'm afraid I'm not much use beyond that -- I don't know much about Leaflet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up getting this to work by following this example: https://gist.github.com/ZJONSSON/2957559

Here is the working code:

```
var path = d3.geo.path().projection(function project(x) {
    var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(x[1], x[0]));
    return [point.x, point.y];
}).pointRadius(function(d) {
    return 2;
});

/* Load and project/redraw on zoom */
d3.json("static/out.json", function(collection) {
    var feature = g.selectAll("path")
        .data(collection.features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", function(d) {
            return d.properties.category + " " + d.properties.investigates + " " + d.properties.thumbnail;
        }).attr("id", function(d) {
            return d.properties.address;
        }).attr("lat", function(d) {
            return Math.abs(d.geometry.coordinates[1]);
        }).attr("long", function(d) {
            return Math.abs(d.geometry.coordinates[0]);
        })
        .attr("d", path);

    map.on("viewreset", function reset() {
        feature.attr("d", path);
    });
    loadThumbs();
});
```

Comment: I hit a similar issue in the context of placing an object defined by an svg path on a Leaflet map using D3. The objects placed correctly using a transform() on PCs but, using the same browser and version, randomly space shifted on a laptop - just like in your example. The approach that worked for me was to ensure the svg path was relative and then to use the desired lat/lng (converted to leaflet points of course) as the opening 'm' value. No transform was then needed and the placement was exactly right on both PCs and laptops.

There is definately something odd somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you're calling `d3.json`.

```
d3.json('{{url_for('static', filename='out.json') }}', //...
```

isn't valid. The [`d3.json`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_json) function expects its first parameter to be a URL string, not an object. In both FF and webkit you're probably getting random garbage and that's what your code uses to calculate the bounds.

Are you trying to use a template (i.e. mustache) to construct the URL? If so, you're forgetting to render the template.

Comment: @StephenTthomas, those brackets are a jinja2 template -- I think it gets translated into a standard URL string by the time it gets to the client. I am not getting garbage in chrome/safari -- I think it is an issue w/ FF.